# Handling int and std::vector::size_type in comparsion

Tags: c++, int, c++03, size-type

So I have something like this (C++03):

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...
}

class something
{
    private:
        std::vector<MyClass*> container;
    // ...
}

// cmdarg can be anything, negative int too...
void something::foo(const std::string& cmdarg)
{
    const int res = std::stoi(cmdarg);
    if (res >= 0 && static_cast<std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type>(res) < this->container.size())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would like to ask if the conversion from `int` to `std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type` is valid. The `res >= 0` says it's non negative, so I guess converting to an another non-negative number is okey.

My problem is, if I write

```
if (res >= 0 && res < container.size())
```

I get a warning, because of comparsion with signed and unsigned integer types.

My above code (the full one) compiles and seems to work, but I'm not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are sure that int will never be negative, then you can declare it as size_t or cast it to size_t

Comment: This looks to me like something for the code review stack exchange

Comment: In practice, using `static_cast<unsigned>` or `static_cast<size_t>` is enough.  What you've shown there would be appropriate if you were writing a template.

Comment: I suppose the warning doesn't take into account if the comparison is executed or not, just checks the types. Casting is fine to make the warning go away, `std::size_t` is rather unlikely to be less than `unsigned int`.

Comment: @JHBonarius: If cmdarg == "-5" for example, it gives a big positive inteteger and res >= 0 is true.

Comment: @JHBonarius How do you detect that the input is incorrect? You've lost that information.

Comment: `res < container.size()` is still there... I never said that could be dropped...but forget it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a bit too perfect for my taste.

Breaking it down:

```
const int res = std::stoi(cmdarg);
if (res >= 0 && static_cast<std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type>(res) < this->container.size())
```

The if-statement for checking below zero is nice. Personally I would write this as:

```
if (res < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Negative number " << res <<" given for ..., a positive was expected" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

This leads us to the cast:

```
auto unsigned_res = static_cast<std::vector<MyClass*>::size_type>(res);
```

However, size_type this vector always `size_t` as it uses the `std::allocator`. In code review, I would request to change this for readability to:

```
auto unsigned_res = static_cast<std::size_t>(res);
```

Finally, you can indeed nicely compare it:

```
if (unsiged_res < container.size())
    // Do something
```

Note that I mentioned both the comparison and the cast, as this needs to happen in that order. On top of that, you also need some exception handling for when `std::stoi` fails, see [it's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

For more details on how to correctly deal with signed/unsigned, I can recommend [this article](http://ithare.com/c-thoughts-on-dealing-with-signedunsigned-mismatch/) on ithare.